# bcp queryout not saving to local

Tags: sql-server, bcp

query

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from DEV.DBO.visit" queryout "c:\users\visit.txt" -c -T'
```

above works ok and saves output on the remote server;
what i am trying to do here is to save it on my machine that 
i launched SQL from

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `xp_cmdshell`, you're literally running a command **on the SQL Server**: the C: drive is the SQL Server's hard drive. To save the output to your machine, your machine will have to have a network share that's visible to the SQL Server. Then you can run the command like this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from DEV.DBO.visit"
  queryout "\\my-computer\my-share\users\visit.txt" -c -T'
```

However, since the command is running under the credentials of the SQL Server, that share also must be writable by the SQL Server account. Which is probably isn't.

The bigger question is, ***Why are you running `bcp` on the server instead of running `bcp` locally?***

Open a command shell, and just say:

```
bcp "select * from dev.dbo.visit"
  queryout c:\my-bcp-output-data.txt
  -S some-sql-server-instance
  -T
```

Comment: a question.. even if you run the `bcp` command using command shell, you are logging in to the database as a user and executing these queries..correct?

Comment: Yes but when you run BCP locally the results are returned locally. (i.e. wherever the BCP.EXE is executing)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently. The results of `queryout` are written on to the database server. A way around this is to use a `ftp` to transfer the resulting files from the (remote) server on to your local machine.

You can also ask the DBA to provide permissions so the SSMS client can write to your local machine.